# Where can I find the video of Apollo 16 floodlight mistaken with a UFO?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, apollo-program, video

So, [a few years ago (2004) NASA showed that a picture of a supposed UFO captured by the Apollo 16 astronauts through the window of the Command Module was in fact the floodlight protruding from the module itself](https://web.archive.org/web/20080730012805/http://www.nasa.gov/vision/space/travelinginspace/no_ufo.html).

I would like to know were to find the actual video footage. There is a [low resolution version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQGZQO6V1PM) on YouTube, but I would like to find the footage from a better source (NASA, JPL...) and with better quality. Looking at the picture shown in the NASA article it is clear that there is a much better quality video out there:

[image]

NASA says that

> The images were captured with a 16mm motion picture camera shooting at 12 frames per second from a command/service module window

so I guess it is not TV footage. I also would like to have the report since apparantly there's one

> Gregory Byrne of Johnson Space Center's Image Science and Analysis Group completed a report on its investigation earlier this year.

Is it publicly available?

Comment: Today I learned there was a CM EVA floodlight.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's what _they_ want you to think.

Comment: In 2005 Spaceflight Films put out their usual exemplary and complete 20-hour 6-DVD set for Apollo 16. Likely the footage is included since they tended to include everything available, but there is no way to know if they obtained the DAC segment that was restored in 2004. I tend to doubt it as they would have likely mentioned it in the set details which can be seen on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20050206161418/http://spacecraftfilms.com/apollo16.htm) website. The DVD set is long out of print, although Spacecraft Films sets sometimes turn up on eBay and Amazon.

Comment: @StevePemberton Why is that 20-hour films not in YouTube? Lots of interesting clips there for sure.

Comment: Swike - NASA mostly creates video content that is geared towards the general public. Only space geeks like us want to see high resolution Apollo footage of capsule appendages. Presumably the restored film is available to someone who wants to go through the procedural process of accessing it at NASA, and then posting it on YouTube. That just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Yeah @Swike unfortunately not all of humanity cares quite so much about the specific positioning of an external lamp during transit to the moon...
(:

Comment: @AntiElonGuy I care because this is a great example of an "ufological" fail. Also I expected all NASA recordings to be publicly available by now on some of their databases, so I was really hoping there was a way to access.

Comment: @Swike Sorry if you missinterpreted my message, I was merely making a jab at the lack of available information, I actually agree it should all be publicly available!
Sorry again!

Comment: Swike - _"I expected all NASA recordings to be publicly available by now on some of their databases"_ this has been an ongoing problem, mainly due to the sheer volume of data. NASA has limited budget and puts priority on current and future missions.  Over the years different NASA centers have done many different websites, but the sites are often incomplete, somewhat poorly organized, and even worse not always maintained, so after several years they often just disappear, sending us scrambling to find the photo or document that we used to find on the NASAxyz.com website which is no longer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after some work I finally found the footage. You can download it from here (4.2 GB):

https://www.dvidshub.net/video/176437/apollo-16-16mm-onboard-film

You can see the supposed UFO from 4:36.